# ios facebook sdk error systemlogincancelled

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook

I am getting a facebook sdk error on ios when I try to login -- note that I just upgraded the version of my facebook sdk to version 3.21.1. The interesting thing is that it works fine on the simulator. When I log into facebook on my iphone under settings => facebook the facebook login on my app fails, but when I disconnect the native facebook login it works fine again.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray * basicPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends", @"email"];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:basicPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

    [DCTLogger debug:@"facebookLoginQ:Callback: %@/%p sess=%@ ", [DCTBase stringForFBSessionState:status], error, session];
    if (error) {
        dispatch_async(q, ^{
            handlerCopy(nil, error);
        });

        return;
    }

    if (status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        [self facebookSessionCreatedQ:q Callback:handlerCopy];
    }
}];
```

The error I get is `com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled` with facebook sdk error code 2.

Another interesting point is that if I remove `public_profile` from `basicPermissions` the login works fine, and as per another post I saw about this, if I use the deprecated method of `openActiveSessionWithPermissions` as opposed to `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` it works fine as well.

Just want to point out again that it only seems to fail when there is a natively logged in facebook account on the device. I have a feeling that perhaps the new sdk automatically includes `public_profile` so if I request it again in basicPermissions it causes an issue.

Comment: I've done some more testing, and the error only occurs if I use the system login (i.e. native login). I can force the fbook sdk to use the facebook app / webview instead of using native and it works fine. However I would like for the system login to work as well.